# JavaFX 8: Stage insets (window decoration thickness)?

Tags: java, border, javafx-8, stage, window-decoration

How can i determine the stage/window insets in JavaFX? In Swing i could simple write:

```java
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
```

What would be the equivalent in JavaFX to get the size of the border and the titlebar of the window?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can determine these by looking at the bounds of the scene relative to the width and height of the window.

Given a `Scene scene;`, `scene.getX()` and `scene.getY()` give the x and y coordinates of the `Scene` within the window. These are equivalent to the left and top insets, respectively.

The right and bottom are slightly trickier, but

```
scene.getWindow().getWidth()-scene.getWidth()-scene.getX()
```

gives the right insets, and similarly

```
scene.getWindow().getHeight()-scene.getHeight()-scene.getY()
```

gives the bottom insets.

These values will of course only make sense once the scene is placed in a window and the window is visible on the screen.

If you really want an `Insets` object you can do something like the following (which would even stay valid if the border or title bar changed size after the window was displayed):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.binding.ObjectBinding;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class WindowInsetsDemo extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label topLabel = new Label();
        Label leftLabel = new Label();
        Label rightLabel = new Label();
        Label bottomLabel = new Label();


        VBox root = new VBox(10, topLabel, leftLabel, bottomLabel, rightLabel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);


        ObjectBinding<Insets> insets = Bindings.createObjectBinding(() -> 
        new Insets(scene.getY(), 
                primaryStage.getWidth()-scene.getWidth() - scene.getX(), 
                primaryStage.getHeight()-scene.getHeight() - scene.getY(), 
                scene.getX()),
                scene.xProperty(),
                scene.yProperty(),
                scene.widthProperty(),
                scene.heightProperty(),
                primaryStage.widthProperty(),
                primaryStage.heightProperty()
            );

        topLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Top: "+insets.get().getTop(), insets));
        leftLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Left: "+insets.get().getLeft(), insets));
        rightLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Right: "+insets.get().getRight(), insets));
        bottomLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.createStringBinding(() -> "Bottom: "+insets.get().getBottom(), insets));

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```